# Getting a selected radio buttons label?

Tags: radio-button, label

I have a group of radio buttons and I am getting the selected one out of this group like this:

```
var selectedRadio= Form.getInputs('my_form','radio','options[22]').find(function(radio) { 
        return radio.checked; 
    });
```

Now there is a label for each of the radio buttons and I want to get the one for this selected radio button. The radio button has id="options_22_2" for example and the label looks like that:

```
<label id="options_22_2label" for="options_22_2">
    labels text
</label>
```

So what I want is *labels text*. Any chance to get that label? Maybe using the ids or something? Its ok to use prototype.

Thanks!

**Solved:** I now get the id of the selected radio and then get the innerHTML of the label using this id.

Comment: In which language is your program? Java? Add the label maybe too

Comment: Its an application written in PHP, but I think this does not matter for my problem? My problem can be solved using JS/Prototype, I just dont know how :).